# Add an "exclude module" rule to an entry in plugin.xml for Cordova 5

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, gradle, bolts-framework

After updating Cordova to `5.3.3`, I had to update the facebook connect plugin, specifically `cordova-plugin-facebook4`. The thing is that, after a lot of issues, I managed to get stuck into this error:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lbolts/AggregateException;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

I know that it's because the `bolts-android` library is set twice in the project. I already did an `exclude module "bolts-android"` inside the compile facebook sdk statement. However, when I run a `cordova compile`, it overrides the `build.gradle` and removes my change (obviously).

The thing is, **can I set an `exclude module` rule in the `plugin.xml` file?** This is the line that includes the facebook library (I guess):

```
<framework src="com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+"/>
```